# How to map words to vocabulary index in TF 2.0 without eager execution

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, eager-execution

I have a Keras model that trains find when eager mode is on (TF 2.1.0). One of my features is a string that I need to map to its corresponding vocabulary index. However, with eager execution disabled, I cannot find a neat way to do this.

I was initially using `tft.apply_vocabulary`, which used to work fine but fails without eager execution. I also tried `tf.lookup.StaticVocabularyTable`:

```
table = tf.lookup.StaticVocabularyTable(TextFileIdTableInitializer('item_vocab.txt'), 1)
out = table.lookup(input_strings)
```

which (with eager mode off) fails with:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Table not initialized.
>        [[{{node transformer/hash_table_Lookup_1/hash_table_Lookup/LookupTableFindV2}}]]

I am able to run the table's `_initialize` method in a `tf.Session`, but that feels like too much work for such a common task and is not TF2.0 compatible.

So, how do you map strings to integer indexes from a vocab file without eager execution?

### Why not eager?

I have the impression that graph mode training has wider support (e.g. multi-gpu training) and better performance and I'm trying to make sure my code works with eager mode disabled, so that I can eventually tunr it off when I'm done developing. Is that a sensible goal?

Comment: If you have an answer by now mind posting it?

Comment: I couldn't do this outside eager mode. I'm still using apply_vocabulary.
One possible alternative that I haven't tried yet is to use feature_columns and create an embedding feature column (instead of Keras embedding layer). That will take a string and return the corresponding embedding (as opposed to Keras embedding layer which expects an integer index as its input)